# ffmpeg "non monotonically increasing dts" error when streaming and encoding on the fly

Tags: python, ffmpeg, encoding, streaming

I have a script which is encoding files on the fly and streaming them to a server using ffmpeg. After a couple of hours I tend to get an error

```
[mp3 @ 0000021084a3bc00] Application provided invalid, non monotonically increasing dts to muxer in stream 0: 188914329 >= 188610764
```

I'm not completely sure what's causing this. This error is quickly followed by

```
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Unknown error
```

and

```
Error writing trailer of server: Error number -10053 occurred.
```

Then,

```
size=  175402kB time=01:14:42.65 bitrate= 320.5kbits/s speed=   1x
video:0kB audio:175403kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
```

```
Conversion failed!
```

I'm using python and the commands I'm using are:

```
encProcess = subprocess.Popen(['ffmpeg', '-y', '-i', file, '-vn', '-codec:a', 'libmp3lame', '-ar', '44100', '-ac', '2', '-b:a', '320k', 'ffmpeg-files/temp' + str(i) + '.mp3'], shell=True)


streamProcess = subprocess.Popen(['ffmpeg', '-re', '-vn', '-i', 'ffmpeg-files/list_1.txt', '-f', 'mp3', '-safe', '0', '-c', 'copy', 'icecast://source:password@site:1234/mount'], shell=True)
```

I run the encoding process after the duration of the previous file as completed, so in theory it shouldn't run into issues, but I think perhaps there's a problem with this and it ends up overwriting a file that is being read. Essentially I'm running a while loop with `time.sleep((startTime - time.time() + trackDuration)/1000` at the end of it, with an offset of a few seconds. I'm sure there must be a better way, and I think that this is whats causing the issue.

Any suggestions for how to improve/fix this are very much appreciated.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: These are the full ffmpeg error messages @furas